# Only Copying the Latest Folder/Files for a specific day with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Thanks Steve i have followed your steps and my pipeline job now runs successfully, but the destination table does not populate with any data, can you please check to see where i went wrong?

Pipeline Output:

[image]

Variables and For Each container Details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Steve, will do looking into your fix today and will notify you of the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot of my test pipeline:**

[image]

**Step:**
1.create two variable.

[image]

2.create a Get Metadata activity.

[image]
[image]

3.create a For Each activity and use this expression(check Sequential option):

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`
[image]

4.inside of For Each activity:

[image]

[image]

[image]

5.copy activity:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve, i have updated my original Post with my latest findings, can you kindly assist?

Comment: @RaynoMatthee sorry for so late to reply you. I have updated my answer, you can follow this step(change my filepath to your filepath).If you have any doubt, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Steve, i will look into your solution today and provide feedback soon. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help Steve the design you provided now works successfully. Have a great day.